# How to disable button 'makehomepage' if already set as home page?

Tags: javascript, html

On load of the page, I would like to disable a button, that on click sets the home page of my browser to the homepage of interest, if I already have set the homepage to my site.

Does anybody have any thoughts on this?

At the moment I know how to make a button that sets my home page to www.myhomepage.com, i.e. see script below, but basically I need two things:

- how to check whether my home page is already set to www.myhomepage.com
- a script that disables the button

http://www.myhomepage.com');" value="Set this page as your Home Page!" />

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible. The DOM will not load or detect what homepage a user has set so there is no way to compare.

If someone clicks the button, you can easily disable it after that, or even set a cookie to read and compare on later visits. However, if the user sets their home page manually, there's no way to detect that.

Comment: thanx. but how would I do this with cookies?

Comment: See here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html. So you set a cookie triggered by the click event of your button. And on page load, read the cookie. If it exists, disable the button.